# Перевод из Десятичная система счисления в восьмеричную

Tags: java

Изучаю Java совсем недавно и ни как не могу разобраться с алгоритмом преобразования десятичной системы в восьмеричную. Ни как не могу понять зачем нужен метод (Math.pow(10, i) для чего он здесь? Что он дает? Можно ли обойтись без него?

```
int decimal = 15450; 
int octal = 0;
for (int i = 0; 0 < decimal; i++){
    octal = (int)(octal + (decimal % 8)*(Math.pow(10, i)));
    decimal = decimal / 8;
}
System.out.println(octal);
```

Comment: Вы нашли очень плохой код. Степень десятки, вещественные числа - всё это не нужно. Выбросьте его и печатайте по-циферно задом наперед.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем коде происходят две вещи. Первая: из числа извлекаются цифры в восьмеричной системе счисления:

- *15450 = 8 · 1931 + **2***;
- *1931 = 8 · 241 + **3***;
- *241 = 8 · 30 + **1***;
- *30 = 8 · 3 + **6***;
- *3 = 8 · 0 + **3***.

Выделенные цифры образуют восьмеричное представления числа: *15450<sub>10</sub> = **36132**<sub>8</sub>*.

Вторая вещь: восьмеричные цифры умножаются на степени десятки: ***3**·10<sup>4</sup> + **6**·10<sup>3</sup> + **1**·10<sup>2</sup> + **3**·10<sup>1</sup> + **2**·10<sup>0</sup> = **36132**<sub>10</sub>*.

Полученное десятичное число выглядит на печати как восьмеричное. Получился нужный результат - программа напечатала восьмеричное представление десятичного числа.

Это плохой способ из-за переполнения. *1000000000<sub>10</sub> = 7346545000<sub>8</sub>*. Но *7346545000<sub>10</sub> > 2147483647<sub>10</sub> = 2<sup>31</sup> - 1* - максимальное значение `int`. Во время печати произойдёт переполнение, вы получите чепуху.

То что задействована вещественная арифметика тоже программу не красит.

Это рабочий, корявый, избыточный способ печатать небольшие целые числа в восьмеричном формате.

Рабочее решение (одно из) состоит в том чтобы накопить цифры в буфере, развернуть буфер задом-наперёд и напечатать. Никаких переполнений и загадочных вещественных вычислений:

```
int decimal = 15450;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int n = decimal; n > 0; n /= 8) {
    sb.append(n % 8);
}
if (sb.length() == 0) {
    sb.append(0);
}
System.out.println(sb.reverse());
```

Answer (score 0):

Это метод здесь нужен, чтобы получить очередную цифру "восьмеричного представления" числа путем умножения восьмеричной цифры `(decimal % 8)` на степень десятки. Почему десятки? - да потому что выбран такой способ упаковки восьмеричных цифр в целое число, что его строковое представление совпадает со строковым восьмеричным представлением исходного числа.

Нужен ли метод pow здесь на самом деле? С точки зрения оптимизации - нет, даже вреден, вещественная арифметика тут нафиг не нужна. С точки зрения написавшего - наверное, нужен, ему так кажется короче и понятнее.

Вот без него:

```
    int decimal = 15450; 
    int octal = 0;
    for (int p10 = 1; 0 < decimal; p10 *= 10){
        octal = octal + (decimal % 8) * p10;
        decimal = decimal / 8;
    }
    System.out.println(octal);
```

Comment: перепаковывать число в десятично-восьмеричный формат само по себе зло. Во-первых, может не влезть, во-вторых не нужно.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy Ну эт понятно, я про способ не стал уж ругаться, только обиняками.

Answer (score 0):

Использование вещественной арифметики и приведения типа излишне.

Чтобы получить строку в нужной системе счисления, существуют стандартные методы [`Integer::toOctalString(int i)`](https://javadoc.scijava.org/Java11/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#toOctalString(int)), или же в любую целочисленную систему [`Integer::toString(int i, int radix)`](https://javadoc.scijava.org/Java11/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#toString(int,int)) / [`Integer::toUnsignedString(int i, int radix)`](https://javadoc.scijava.org/Java11/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#toUnsignedString(int,int))

Если задача реализовать своё преобразование, чтобы десятичное число выглядело как восьмеричное, можно использовать побитовые операции:

```java
public static int toOct(int dec) {
    int sign = dec < 0 ? -1 : dec > 0 ? 1 : dec; // запомнить знак
    dec *= sign;
    int res = 0;
    int p = 1;
    while (dec > 0) {
        res += p * (dec & 07); // взять три последних бита 0b111
        dec >>= 3;             // сдвиг вправо вместо деления
        p *= 10;               // следующий "восьмеричный" разряд
    }
    return sign * res;
}
```

Тесты

```
System.out.println(toOct(15));   // 17
System.out.println(toOct(-15));  // -17
System.out.println(toOct(65));   // 101
System.out.println(toOct(3200)); // 6200
```